# Get referenced node fields in twig

Tags: theming, 8, entities

In Drupal 8, I have a content type, that has an "entity_reference" field and I wish to access the referenced node's fields in twig template.
the kint() output for the field is:
[image]

In this list I can't find the referenced node's field values. How can I (if at all possible) load the node or node fields/values in twig?

Best,

Alari

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The referenced nodes are inside the list and you can get the first list item with `.0`, the referenced node with `.entity` and then the first field value:

For example if you are in a page or node template:

```
{{ node.field_reference.0.entity.field_in_referenced_node.0.value }}
```

You can ommit `.0` in both cases, when you only want to get the first value.

Other examples could look like this, but your question is unclear exactly where you are:

```
{{ item.content['#item'].entity.field_in_referenced_node.value }}
{{ elements['#items'].0.entity.field_in_referenced_node.value }}
```

**Edit: Counting the items in multivalue fields**

```
{{ node.field_reference.getvalue|length }}
```

You can't use `count()` in twig, because this is not on the whitelist for allowed methods. This uses `getvalue()` to get the array of the field and then counts the array keys.

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm! Where can I learn more about what elements are contained/found where with twig?

Comment: can you tell how can I get the items count ?

Comment: i had an entity reference to a menu and this worked for me (in page.html.twig): `node.field_related_menu.0.target_id`